# Telerik RadListView Binding Issue in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, telerik, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I'm facing problem in binding the data radlistview by using it in xamarin forms. The code mentioned below is working fine with me in a single array

```
var listView = new RadListView();
listView.ItemsSource = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" };
```

but when to use the syntax of binding in multidemensional array like this

```
List<List<string>> strings = new List<List<string>>()
{
   new List<string>{"Id:001","Name:Decker1"},
   new List<string>{"Id:002","Name:Decker2"}
};
```

Data is not binding. The data is coming from Api 
Please help figure out the problem where im missing and guide me so that i can bind the data in radlistview of telerik from api.

Answer (score 0):

Your first list is just a list of strings so the listview can just do a ToString and get the value.

The second one if it does a ToString it wont get any string just a System.Object or something similar.

You either need to create a list of classes with properties and define these in the listview or flatten your multi dimensional array into a single dimension again.